# Заменить оператор неравенство на символ - ≠ (not equal to)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Как в VS заменить символ неравенства с

```
if (x != y) {...}
```

на

```
if (x ≠ y) {...}
```

Comment: А чего все в минусах то?

Comment: @srvr4vr Сначала этот вопрос был задан на английском языке и его заминусовали, т.к. это не поправилам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует использовать Fira Code: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

1) Скачать по ссылке и установить

2) Поставить этот шрифт в настройках VS